# accessing iTunes Lyrics data in Java on Windows

Tags: java, windows, itunes

I am writing a short Java program that downloads the lyrics from a website.  The only problem is that I don't know how to access the lyrics tab in the mp3 file.  Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

[JAudioTagger](http://www.jthink.net/jaikoz/) is a more complete library than javamusictag.

Answer (score 0):

You need a library to edit the tags in the mp3 file.

Have a look at: http://javamusictag.sourceforge.net/index.html